# Has Submitting Queue Without Command Buffer valid usage?

Tags: vulkan

What is the valid use case to call `vkQueueSubmit` with `VkSubmitInfo` command buffers parameters set to 0 count and `nullptr` pointer?

*Example code:*

```
  VkFenceCreateInfo fenceInfo{};
  VkFence fence;
  vkCreateFence(device, &fenceInfo, nullptr, &fence);

  std::vector<VkSubmitInfo> submitInfos;
  VkSubmitInfo submitInfo{};
  ...
  submitInfo.commandBufferCount = 0;
  submitInfo.pCommandBuffers = nullptr;
  ...
  
  submitInfos.push_back(submitInfo);

  vkQueueSubmit(queue, submitInfos.size(), submitInfos.data(), fence);
```

I can think just about one thing and that is signaling the fence, but it makes no sense for me to do it this way (as it can be reseted or created in signaled state).

**Is there any (other) valid use case for doing so?**

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the question. Why does it matter if it might somehow be useful to do this? The behavior of an empty batch is well-defined by the specification. So what are you interested in learning here?

Comment: @NicolBolas I was just curious what might be the sensible use-case for submitting to the queue without any command buffer pinned to submit, because I could not think about any such one when discussing this topic.